# Show that a vectorial subspace $W$ invariant under a linear transformation $T$ is the kernel of $T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ a finite vectorial space and $T:V\to V$ a linear transformation. Show that if $W$ is  a subspace of $V$ invariant under $T$ so that $V={\rm{Im}}(T)\oplus W$ then $W=\ker T$.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried with the range-nulity theorem but I not Have exit!

Comment: for any $w\in W$, $w\in Im(T)$ by definition. But $W$ is $T$ invariant, what does it mean?

Comment: why if $w\in W$ then $w\in$ Im(T)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $w\in W$. Then $T(w)\in\DeclareMathOperator{image}{image}\image(T)$ and $T(w)\in W$ since $W$ is $T$-invariant. That is, $T(w)\in\image(T)\cap W$. But $\image(T)\cap W=\{\vec 0\}$ since $V=\image(T)\oplus W$. Thus $T(w)=\vec 0$. This shows that $W\subset \ker(T)$.

Now, the rank-nullity theorem implies
$$
\dim\ker(T)=\dim(V)-\dim\image(T)=\dim(V)-\{\dim(V)-\dim(W)\}=\dim(W)
$$
Hence $W=\ker(T)$.

Comment: Shouldn't we leave a few gaps for the sake of OP's pleasure/curiosity?

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint: }$ Use Im$(T)\cap W = \{0\}$. Hence $T(v) = 0 \iff v \in $Im$(T)$$\cap W$. Use this to show the two containments.